# Landing Page : Learn More || Scroll Down || Nothing?

Tags: landing-page

For long single-pages:

I'm of the camp that is for adding a CTA button vs no button. 
But i would ideally love to hear from anyone who has tested this at scale with hard #s.

*this is for both desktop and mobile. 
[image: Landing Page]

thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, clicking the button would just scroll you to below the fold?

Comment: yes that would be the trick.

Comment: @devin - Video backgrounds a big no-no? please sight references..cause last time i checked, most of the web was using it :

[1] http://www.apple.com/music/
[2] https://www.squarespace.com/
[3] http://invisionapp.com 
[4] https://www.airforce.com/

Comment: interesting.. high-profile brand power now powers UX.

Comment: sorry, this is pointless. deleted everything